# TreeBagger() (MATLAB) and different number of variables on train and test set

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using MATLAB function TreeBagger() for Random Forest classification, for an assignment. It gives error when the number of variables of the Test data is different from the number of variables of the Training data.

I have been taught that variable selection should be done on training data only, not on test data, so that there is no bias on the test data. So after spliting the initial dataset (50 variables) to training and test set, I perform variable selection (chi-square test of independence) on the training set. So the training set consists of 37 variables, whereas the test set remains with 50 variables.

I used [TreeBagger()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html) to train the training set and then I used the test set for prediction (function [predict()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.predict.html)). And I get an error because the number of variables of the test set is different from the number of variables that the model was trained on.

Is it wrong to perform variable selection on the training set only? Is there a way I can perform the prediction using this function?

Answer (score 1):

The selected variables are a part of your final model.
This means that the final model has to use only the variables selected on the training set whenever you want to use it.
Thus, before applying your TreeBagger model, you filter out the variables that were not selected and then apply it to get predictions on your test set.

Comment: thank you! I had understood it totally wrong in the first place.